# Docker + Nodejs + Brunch + ReactJS image

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, dockerfile, brunch

I'm trying to setup my development environment just installing Docker on my laptop. First container that I'm going to create is Node.js + Brunch.io + ReactJS.

On my Ubuntu 16.04 host I've created a directory

```
mkdir /home/username/Development/projectname/
```

Inside of **projectname** folder I've cloned the [brunch/with-react](https://github.com/brunch/with-react) skeleton repo by running

```
git clone https://github.com/brunch/with-react.git www
```

Inside of **www** directory created a Dockerfile

```
FROM node:6.3.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes npm
WORKDIR /opt

COPY package.json /opt  
RUN npm install

COPY . /opt
RUN npm install -g brunch/brunch
RUN brunch build

EXPOSE 3333

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Build the image launching

```
docker build . -t brunch
```

Then I start the container by running:

```
docker run -d -P --name web brunch
```

Checking the logs

```
docker logs web
```

And the output says that the server is launched and listening on port 3333

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.3
npm info using node@v6.3.1
npm info lifecycle projectname_www@0.0.1~prestart: projectname_www@0.0.1
npm info lifecycle projectname_www@0.0.1~start: projectname_www@0.0.1

> projectname_www@0.0.1 start /opt
> brunch watch --server

04 Aug 04:48:34 - info: application started on http://localhost:3333/
04 Aug 04:48:35 - info: compiled 174 files into 3 files, copied index.html in 2.5 sec
```

Checking running container statuses

```
docker ps
```

The output

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
efd43b57c23f        brunch              "npm start"         3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:32771->3333/tcp   web
```

Launching web browser on

```
http://localhost:32771
```

But the page is not loading. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3GHi.png).

What am I doing wrong?

**** **EDIT** ****

*[SOLVED] ALTERNATIVE WAY*

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:6.3.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yes npm
WORKDIR /opt

COPY package.json /opt  
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3333
```

Inside **www** directory update *brunch-config.js* file:

```
module.exports = {
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        'vendor.js': /^(?!app)/,
        'app.js': /^app/
      }
    },
    stylesheets: {joinTo: 'app.css'}
  },
  server: {
    hostname: '0.0.0.0'
  },
  plugins: {
    babel: {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}
  }
};
```

Running container from **www** directory:

`docker run -P -it -v $PWD:/opt/app/ brunch bash`

This will mount a host volume to container and run it.

```
~/Development/brunch(branch:master*) » docker run -P -it -v $PWD:/opt/app/ brunch bash

root@e0fd2c6bfa66:/opt/app#
```

Run following commands

```
npm install -g brunch/brunch
brunch build
npm start
```

You will see the output

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.3
npm info using node@v6.3.1
npm info lifecycle your-app@0.0.1~prestart: your-app@0.0.1
npm info lifecycle your-app@0.0.1~start: your-app@0.0.1

> your-app@0.0.1 start /opt/app
> brunch watch --server

07 Sep 19:00:41 - info: application started on http://127.0.0.1:3333/ (lo)
07 Sep 19:00:41 - info: application started on http://172.17.0.2:3333/ (eth0)
07 Sep 19:00:43 - info: compiled 174 files into 3 files, copied index.html in 2.8 sec
```

Open another terminal window and run

```
docker ps
```

The output should look like this

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
e0fc2d6bfa66        brunch              "bash"              14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:32771->3333/tcp   berserk_albattani
```

Open your browser

```
http://localhost:32771
```

In this way it is possible to use node.js inside docker container and at the same time store the project files on local host.

If container is already created but stopped, to launch it run

```
docker exec -it container_name bash
npm start
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by the page isn't loading?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRDM2hPbhG-ZzJVVWVoTGJGd3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you try using Brunch from github (`github:brunch/brunch` in `package.json`) and the `-n` brunch option? `brunch w -sn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside brunch-config you have to set

```
  server: {
      hostname: '0.0.0.0'
  },
```